# pandas speedup groupby aggregate on several columns

Tags: pandas, performance, optimization, pandas-groupby, vectorization

I have a requirement to perform groupby operation on dataset where `groupby` code looks like below.

```
    grouped = result_frame.groupby(["source", "target"]).agg(
        {
            "debit": "sum",
            "credit": "sum",
            "names": lambda x: " ".join(set(x)),
            "details": lambda x: " ".join(set(x)),
            "text": lambda x: " ".join(set(x)),
            "probables": "first",
        }
    ).reset_index()
```

This works fine for small datasets but when it comes to a dataset for 1 million or more rows this runs like forever. I need help to optimize this groupby by using numpy vectorize or any other efficient technique feasible.

Comment: ditch the lambdas and use `'unique'`

Comment: how should i combine values of ```grouped``` by rows for textual columns ?